# Pyautogui, como fazer o python esperar até que a imagem apareça

Tags: python, pyautogui

Estou com uma duvida relativamente simples, mas não sei como fazer, estou utilizando o pyautogui para realizar instalação de programas de forma automatica, porém os programas depois que terminarem o pyautogui precisa clicar no botão concluir, porém o tempo de instalação do programa é relativo em cada equipamento, então tem PC que demora mais, e outros demora mesmo, sendo assim não é muito viavel eu colocar um time.sleep nesse caso, mas tem como eu fazer o PyAutoGui esperar esse botão aparecer? Segue meu codigo de maneira resumida:

```
def InstalationReceitaNET(self):
        time.sleep(1)
        pyautogui.click(pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(r'imagens\receitanet\receitanet.png', confidence=0.7))
        for i in range(3): 
            pyautogui.click(pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(r'imagens\receitanet\avancar.png', confidence=0.7))
            time.sleep(1)
        time.sleep(10)        
        pyautogui.click(pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(r'imagens\receitanet\concluir.png', confidence=0.7))
```

Assim funciona, porém o time sleep como falei pode variar muito, fazendo com que o usuario perca muito tempo.

Comment: Uma ideia bem básica, mas dependendo da sua aplicação pode ser suficiente: executar `locateCenterOnScreen` dentro de um laço e ficar tentando enquanto disparar uma exceção de imagem não encontrada.

Comment: Ele deu certo por um lado, mas por outro não deu bom, pois esse loop ficou infinito, e influenciou em outras coisas, eu fiz dessa maneira:

receita = None
        while receita is None: 
            receita = pyautogui.click(pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(r'imagens\ReceitaBX\simreinstalar.png', confidence=0.7))

Comment: opa, eu vi essa postagem e esqueci de contribuir, você aceitaria uma solução com outra lib? Existe uma lib que tem uma api bem parecida com a pyautogui, que é o pywinauto, lá ele possui um método helper `wait_cpu_usage_lower`. Veja a [documentação](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/pywinauto.application.html?highlight=cpu#pywinauto.application.Application.wait_cpu_usage_lower)

Comment: Basicamente o que essa função helper faz é ficar observando se o nível de processamento da máquina fica abaixo de algum limiar.

Comment: Talvez você possa aproveitar o código fonte atual com essa outra lib, ou então tentar implementar essa lógica de verificar o limiar de processamento da máquina em seu código atual.

Answer (score -2):

Eu passei por um problema parecido recentemente, mas com o código abaixo consegui resolver. A ideia é basicamente fazer com que o PyAutoGui procure até que o resultado seja diferente de None. Caso fique muito tempo procurando, chama uma função de report (como roda numa outra máquina, é só para eu saber e ir tratar)

```
nameLogin = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(r'img\nameLogin.png', confidence=0.9)
contador =0
print("Wait, I'm looking")
while(nameLogin == None):
    nameLogin = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(r'img\nameLogin.png', confidence=0.9)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    contador +=1
    if(contador >=12000):
        informError(i)

print('Insere login')
pyautogui.click(nameLogin, duration=0.4)
pyautogui.typewrite('vinicius.brandalize')
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, acho que isso vai salvar muito aqui

Comment: Por  nada Renan. Só peço que caso resolva o poblema, sinalize aqui